# where should i put the file composer

Tags: composer-php

according to a document from getcomposr.org. It should be place on

> usr/local/bin

.

in my case...the directory

> usr/local/bin

not exist. but instead directory

> /bin

existe.

so should i create

> usr/local/bin

and move composer there 
or
just move into

> /bin

thanks you in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should read further in the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-macos):

> Note: On some versions of macOS the `/usr` directory does not exist by default. If you receive the error "/usr/local/bin/composer: No such file or directory" then you must create the directory manually before proceeding: `mkdir -p /usr/local/bin`.

This `mkdir` call should be run with `sudo`.

Also note that you can easily install Composer with [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/composer) via `brew install composer`.

Comment: it protected...should i make chmod 777

Comment: Protected? Just do `sudo mkdir ...`.